# What is wrong with my installation of Koala?

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, sass

I just installed Koala on my Ubuntu 12.04 system. When I try to compile my `.scss` files, I get the following error message:

```
/home/tylerschade/loancalculator/style.scss
/usr/share/koala/bin/sass:4:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
from /usr/share/koala/bin/sass:4
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby < 1.9, the `rubygems` gem is not installed automatically. You need to install it manually before you use anything that depends on a gem.

In your system, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems
```

You may also have to write

```
require "rubygems"
```

somewhere in a Ruby file.

By the way, it is a bad idea to be using Ruby 1.8 at this time.

Comment: How would I install this? I tried this: `tylerschade@ubuntu:~$ sudo gem install rubygem` and got this:`ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rubygem' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rubigen, rubyce, rubychem, rubycom, ruby_ex` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not `rubygem`, it is `rubygems`. Sorry, I may have confused you before the edit.